# problem with equation length alignment

Tags: equations

In fact, I have two equations but the numbering of the first one isn't parallel to the second one here is the code :

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{align}

 \dot{M}_{JS} &=\frac{\sigma X_s Z_r}{m_l u_{ab}}(\frac{-O_rS_s}{\sigma 
 R_L}-\dot{D}_{Eref}+\frac{sV_{AR}^2}{L_s}-\omega_rY_s+\frac{CL_m^2U_{JS}^4}
 {\sigma S_L^2 R_L})-K.sin(sty)  \\

  dot{N}_{JS} &=\frac{\sigma V_s V_r}{m_l u_{ab}}(\frac{-F_rG_s}{\sigma 
  H_L}-\dot{D}_{Oref}+\frac{MV_{AD}^2}{R_R}-\omega_qY_s+\frac{‌​
  CL_m^2U_{JS}^4} {\sigma S_L^2 R_L})
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How can I make a good look of these equations

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

what about this rearrangement:

[image]

this rearrangement is based on my observation that your first and the second equation differ only in the last term:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\dot{N}_{JS}
    & = \frac{\sigma X_s Z_r}{m_l u_{ab}}
        \left(\frac{-O_rS_s}{\sigma R_L} - \dot{D}_{\mathit{Eref}} + \frac{sV_{AR}^2}{L_s} -
        \omega_rY_s + \frac{CL_m^2U_{JS}^4}{\sigma S_L^2 R_L}\right)    \\
\dot{M}_{JS}
    & = \dot{N}_{JS} - K\sin(sty)
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

after edited question we know, that equation is not so related as one conclude from the first question version. see, if this is what you looking for:

[image]

your equations has more issues:

- in `align` environment are not aloved empty lines
- the meaning of `K.sin(sty)` is not clear. in my first solution i convert it to `K\sin(sty)`
- indices `Eref` and `Oref` are not set of variables ... just one. see what is more appropriated to you : `\mathit{Oref}` (as is in *mwe* below) or `O\text{ref}`

since the first equation is to long to fit in text width, one of possible solution (as shown in above image) is split it into two parts:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\dot{M}_{JS}
    & = \frac{\sigma X_s Z_r}{m_l u_{ab}}
        \left(\frac{-O_rS_s}{\sigma R_L} - \dot{D}_{\mathit{Eref}} + \right.    \notag\\
    &\qquad
        \left.\frac{sV_{AR}^2}{L_s} - \omega_rY_s + \frac{CL_m^2U_{JS}^4}{\sigma S_L^2 R_L}
        \right) - K.sin(sty) \\
\dot{N}_{JS}
    & = \frac{\sigma V_s V_r}{m_l u_{ab}}
        \left(\frac{-F_rG_s}{\sigma H_L} - \dot{D}_{\mathit{Oref}} + \frac{MV_{AD}^2}{R_R} - \omega_qY_s + \frac{‌​CL_m^2U_{JS}^4}{\sigma S_L^2 R_L}\right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact it's just an example  I want the full expressions as:\begin{align}

 \dot{M}_{JS} &=\frac{\sigma X_s Z_r}{m_l u_{ab}}(\frac{-O_rS_s}{\sigma 
 R_L}-\dot{D}_{Eref}+\frac{sV_{AR}^2}{L_s}-\omega_rY_s+\frac{CL_m^2U_{JS}^4}
 {\sigma S_L^2 R_L})-K.sin(sty)  \\

  \dot{N}_{JS} &=\frac{\sigma V_s V_r}{m_l u_{ab}}(\frac{-F_rG_s}{\sigma 
 H_L}-\dot{D}_{Oref}+\frac{MV_{AD}^2}{R_R}-\omega_qY_s+\frac{CL_m^2U_{JS}^4}
 {\sigma S_L^2 R_L})
\end{align}
\end{documen

Comment: please, edit your question and add/corect it as you stated in your comment. there more people will see, what you like to achieve.

Comment: @twimo, to my answer i add new solution considering edited question. maybe you like it.